# When I am trying to execute azure template with extension? I am getting below error?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

New - AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment: 5: 33: 31 PM - Resource Microsoft.Compute / virtualMachines / extensions 'dataLin1030Vm/script'
failed with message

```
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [{
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'script'. Error message: \"Script returned an
        error.\n-- - stdout-- - \n\ n-- - errout-- - \nhg - mysql - mongo - instalation.sh: 6: hg - mysql - mongo - instalation.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected\ n\ n\ "."
    }]
}
}
```

Comment: I am executing below arm template: https://github.com/harish-kumar-garg/JsonTemplates/blob/master/Templates/hg-appAndDbVMCreation.json

Answer (score 0):

This:

https://github.com/harish-kumar-garg/JsonTemplates/blob/master/Templates/hg-appAndDbVMCreation.json#L687

Should be pointing to the raw location, e.g.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/harish-kumar-garg/MyShellScripts/master/Scripts/hg-mysql-mongo-instalation.sh

Comment: Thank you, Now it is working, after pointing to raw location.